# Twitter API to Count Hashtag occurrences

Tags: javascript, api, twitter, webserver, hashtag

I need a way to count occurrences of a given Hashtag on Twitter, so that I know exacly how many was found on the twitter.

The main idea was to use the simple  "search" API, but, I would need to iterate trough many pages to know exacly how many, and also, there is a "limit" for the page (which is 1500 tweets), so, if there are more than 1500 tweets, I would read it as 1500.

Is there any other "inteligent" and emproved way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In a word, no.  From the [1.1 API docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets):

> Please note that Twitter's search service and, by extension, the
>   Search API is not meant to be an exhaustive source of Tweets. Not all
>   Tweets will be indexed or made available via the search interface.

The best you can do is to search for the maximum allowed Tweets and iterate through the pages.  Then you can initiate another search using the `since_id` argument for the next batch of 1500. In this way you can step backwards through time, 1500 tweets at a time, for as long as you want (or as long as Twitter makes Tweets available).

Good luck

Comment: That's what i call "Good Adaptation" =]